# Unable to connect Outlook 2007 to Exchange 2007 Internally

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-2007

I am able to connect to Exchange via mobile devices, and OWA, but setting up Outlook clients internally I receive "the action cannot be completed, unable to connect to exchange...."

I've edited the host file for IPv6 loopback issue to no resolve. In a two part question, where do I start to troubleshott his, and do internal clients automatically setup using RCP over HTTP? Or do they setup with FQDN, or the remote DNS HTTPS address?

Comment: DNS resolves fine internally by the way...And can also telnet to 6004

Comment: I was able to finally connect, after manually having to set it up through the external DNS name. If I used https://localname.fqdn.com it is unable to connect. (fqdn not in cert maybe?) My logic tells me internal clients should be using the FQDN before the external address...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add the FQDN of the server to the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are, your auto-discover settings are off. Outlook clients use auto discover to find the exchange servers and if those names are not on the certificates problems can result. Local clients will be using mapi or, maybe even rpc over http if discovery doesn go well. Exchange does have settings for internal and external autodiscovery urls.

Comment: Well Autodiscovery is on, when I add a profile, it detects the user (not quite correctly, name format not right) none-the-less it is active. Do you know how I can check if FQDN is correct in cert?

Comment: scratch, did an Get-ExchangeCertificate |fl    I may have missed the FQDn in the cert. because it's not listed, just has mail.domain.cm and autodiscover.domain.cm  could this be the culprit?